# Number of unique values in every row of a matrix in R

Tags: r, unique

I have this toy matrix:

```
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    3    1    6    8    8    8
[2,]    2    2    5    7    9    7    4
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
```

and I want to keep only the rows with `4` unique elements.

My initial strategy was to use...

```
apply(m, 1, function(x) unique(x))
[[1]]
[1] 1 3 6 8

[[2]]
[1] 2 5 7 9 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

... which would inform R of the unique elements in each row.

Then it would be as simple as `m[length(apply(m, 1, function(x) unique(x)))==4, ]`.

But, not so easy... The output of `apply()`, at least in this case is a list, and hence, I can't use this trick.

Can you help?

Comment: Try `length(unique(x))==4` in your function

Comment: How about `m[apply(m, 1, function(x) length(unique(x))) == 4, ]`. Using `n_distinct()` from `dplyr` is another option.

Comment: @Gopala do you want the points of an accepted answer?

Comment: It is fine. You were almost there. Just a minor adjustment.

Comment: For clarification in case it's helpful, you can test for the equality after the `apply`, like @Gopala said, or inside the `apply` (which is what I was alluding to in my comment). Just in case it's useful in the future.